# How I can get the boxend event in a dragpan or dragzoom interaction of OL3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to make a server petition when the user stops the pan or zoom in the map. I have studied the interactions OL3 code and I have seen that the boxend and boxstart events was launched by the dragbox and dragzoom interactions, but only when the users use the shift key (or whatever key was defined in the  interaction options). In the OL3 docs, only these interactions have defined the events boxend and boxstart, meanwhile the dragpan only have defined the change:active event.

How can I get the pan or zoom stop in OL3?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the moveend event on the Map? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.MapEvent.html?unstable=true#event:moveend

Comment: No, I hadn't seen it. I was studying the ol.interactions and the ol.view looking for events, but not the ol.Map. I will try to use it.

Thanks.